# Sort an arrary in powershell

Tags: powershell

Having trouble sorting this array. I get an error:

```
Sort-Object : Cannot convert System.Int64 t System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock}
```

Not sure what I'm missing...

```
foreach ($objResult in $colResults)
   {$objItem = $objResult.Properties; 
   if ( $objItem.mail.gettype.IsInstance -eq $True) 
      {      
         $user_name = $objItem.name
         $user_email = $objItem.email
         #Transform the DateTime readable format
         $user_logon = [datetime]::FromFileTime($objItem.lastlogon[0])
         $result = $objItem.pwdlastset 
         $user_pwd_last_set = [datetime]::FromFileTime($result[0])

         #calculate the difference in Day from last time a password was set
         $diff_date = [INT]([DateTime]::Now - $user_pwd_last_set).TotalDays;

   $Subtracted = $max_pwd_life - $diff_date
   $dateexpires = $dateexpires = [DateTime]::Now.AddDays($Subtracted);
   $dateexpires = $dateexpires.ToString("dddd (MMM dd, yyyy)")
         if (($Subtracted) -le $max_alert) {
            $selected_user = New-Object psobject
            #$selected_user | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Name" -Value $objItem.name[0]
            $selected_user | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Name" -Value $objItem.Item("displayName")
            $selected_user | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Email" -Value $objItem.mail[0]
            $selected_user | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "LastLogon" -Value $user_logon
            $selected_user | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "LastPwdSet" -Value $user_pwd_last_set
            $selected_user | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "RemainingDays" -Value ($Subtracted)
            $selected_user | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "PasswordExpires" -Value ($dateexpires)
            $userlist+=$selected_user
         }
      }
   }
   $userlist = $userlist | Sort-Object -Property $Subtracted
```

Comment: You need to sort by a property name or an expression based on a property. You are sorting by property `$Subtraced`, which is just a number. Maybe you want to sort by `-Property RemainingDays`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to sort on a property of the corresponding objects in the array. so maybe you wanted to sort by the property with value $Subtracted, which would be "RemainingDays":

```
foreach ($objResult in $colResults) {
    $objItem = $objResult.Properties; 
    if ( $objItem.mail.gettype.IsInstance -eq $True) {      
        $user_name = $objItem.name
        $user_email = $objItem.email
        #Transform the DateTime readable format
        $user_logon = [datetime]::FromFileTime($objItem.lastlogon[0])
        $result = $objItem.pwdlastset 
        $user_pwd_last_set = [datetime]::FromFileTime($result[0])

        #calculate the difference in Day from last time a password was set
        $diff_date = [INT]([DateTime]::Now - $user_pwd_last_set).TotalDays;

        $Subtracted = $max_pwd_life - $diff_date
        $dateexpires = $dateexpires = [DateTime]::Now.AddDays($Subtracted);
        $dateexpires = $dateexpires.ToString("dddd (MMM dd, yyyy)")
        if (($Subtracted) -le $max_alert) {
            $selected_user = New-Object psobject
            #$selected_user | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Name" -Value $objItem.name[0]
            $selected_user | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Name" -Value $objItem.Item("displayName")
            $selected_user | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Email" -Value $objItem.mail[0]
            $selected_user | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "LastLogon" -Value $user_logon
            $selected_user | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "LastPwdSet" -Value $user_pwd_last_set
            $selected_user | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "RemainingDays" -Value ($Subtracted)
            $selected_user | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "PasswordExpires" -Value ($dateexpires)
            $userlist += $selected_user
        }
    }
}
$userlist = $userlist | Sort-Object -Property "RemainingDays"
```